# Issues with drivers for bluetooth usb adaper (dongle) my mic doesn't work

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, microphone

So I have a insignia ns-pcy5bma2-c bluetooth adapter with an ubuntu 108.04 I installed blueman and the output works just fine. But the input is an issue and it doesn't work. When I go to the sound settings and into the input tab I turned it on but it detects no audio and for some reason not only does it not get any input audio, I  hear no output audio. I tried finding the drivers in the software and updates but if found no drivers